# Подскажите регулярно для замены всех символом, кроме ….?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Как заменить все символы в строке кроме первых двух и последних двух ?

Comment: Чем заменить? Опишите вашу проблему.

Comment: заменить спец символом *

Comment: `string.replace(/(?<=^(?:.{2})).*?(?=(?:.{2})$)/, '')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос задан с обширным полем для фантазий )) Попробую и я пованговать:

```js
const str = 'Как заменить все символы в строке кроме первых двух и последних двух';

// Заменить все символы одним символом *
console.log(str.replace(/^(.{2}).*(.{2})$/g, '$1*$2'));
// Каждый символ заменить символом *
console.log(str.substr(0, 2) + str.slice(2,-2).replace(/./g,'*') +  str.substr(-2));
// На всякий случай, каждый символ, кроме пробельных, заменить символом *
console.log(str.substr(0, 2) + str.slice(2,-2).replace(/[^\s]/g,'*') +  str.substr(-2));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log("Как заменить все символы в строке кроме первых двух и последних двух ?".split(" ").map(
  s => s.replace(/^(..).*(..)$/, "$1$2")
).join("\n"))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```

Comment: У вас точно ошибки нет? :)

Comment: @Let'ssayPie, где?

Comment: По-моему здесь не все заменяется. как нужно https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwIS7.png

Comment: @Let'ssayPie, понятия не имею, что ты запускаешь. Вот: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnmYx.png

Answer (score 0):

Регулярки в вашем случае не нужны. Такой код, возможно, будет несколько эффективнее:

```js
let str = "Как заменить все символы в строке кроме первых двух и последних двух?";
let res = [...str].map((e, i) => i<2 || i>=str.length-2 ? e : "*").join("");
console.log(res);
```

Да и доработать его будет проще, например, если не надо менять пробелы:

```
.map((e, i) => i<2 || i>=str.length-2 || e==" " ? e : "*")
```